# Getting downvotes I don't understand

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes

Could someone please tell me what's wrong with this question I asked?, it first got a downvote and no answers, shortly later I changed the question and still I got downvoted again.

I'v asked alot of questions on Stack Exchange and not gotten alot of downvotes. Most when I was programming and the programmers on Stack Overflow didn't think I had enough understanding of the subject.

I'll happily read the post on how to ask a question, but I just don't think it's necessary.

What's wrong with [this](https://superuser.com/questions/814088/using-skype-on-linux-is-it-usable-my-system-is-fedora-20) question?

Comment: If you have specific questions about reception of your questions, you should ask it on that site's meta.  The larger community is not necessarily qualified to judge the question on a specific site.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I've voted to have it moved.

Comment: @somethingSomething - You do understand that questions you delete still count against you right?  So the more questions you delete will increase the chances of you being question banned on Superuser.  Since you deleted the question only moderators can review it.

Comment: @Ramhound That's just silly, if I where a destructive force(small destruct also counts), I would understand, but this is silly.

Comment: @somethingSomething - I don't find it silly.  I don't want people who ask bad questions, to avoid being questioned banned, because they deleted said questions.  Its easy to get positive reputation ask good questions.

Comment: @Ramhound I understand that the communities have guidelines, objectives and such. I'm just saying, It's unfair when I'm new to computers, and I asked those questions when I was starting, I always do some research before asking(sometimes this is looking what I can find in google, and sometimes more), and I feel my questions on StackExchange are getting better.

Comment: I have seen lots of people with a question on a subject they knew very little about  but still asked a quality question, besides, I am just warning you that you removing a question that's been downvote doesn't really doing anything positive